# JSTL forEach not displaying anything

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i am trying to display a JSTL loop using list in a JSP code but it is not displying anything , neither it is giving any type of error nor any result

servlet code :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    String n=req.getParameter("action");
    HttpSession ses = req.getSession();
    String userid = ses.getAttribute("uname").toString();
    if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("viewcart")) {
        ses.setAttribute("cartlist", o.showCart(userid));
        rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/Register/cart.jsp");  
        rd.forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

java function (showCart)

```
List<product> cart=new ArrayList<product>();
try {
    conn = obj.connect();
    String sql="it is working i checked in DB";
    cs=conn.createStatement();  
    rs=cs.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
        product p=new product();
        p.setPname(rs.getString(1));
        p.setQuantity(rs.getString(2));
        p.setPrice(rs.getString(3));
        p.setDtime(rs.getString(4));
        p.setImg(rs.getString(5));
        cart.add(p);  
    }
```

JSP code :

```
<c:forEach items="${cartlist}" var="product">
    <tr>
        <td>jbefjkw<c:out value="${product.pname}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.quantity}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.price}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.dtime}" /></td>
        <td>Rs <c:out value="${product.price}" /></td>
    </tr>
```

product class :

```
public class product {
    private String quantity;
    private String dtime;
    etc ..
    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname=pname;
    }
    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }
    etc and etc ....
```

the query is working in DB i checked multiple times .... the issue is guess with the `forEach` , it is unable to fetch the variables and the loop is not even running once

thnks in advance

Comment: probably, your list never gets any entry added into it. What are  you doing in the catch block of db connection call. Try printing stacktrace in catch block and see if db call is successful

Comment: its already there but i don't see any exception ..`catch(SQLException e)
{ e.printStackTrace();  }`